# How to enable Compiz effects?

Tags: compiz

I have a problem with Compiz. I installed Compiz setting manager on
Ubuntu 12.04, Also installed Compiz main and extra fusion plug-ins. But I can't enable 3D windows and cube reflection effects. The check boxes of these plug-ins doesn't work.

Comment: you can not enable 3D window or cube effect for unity plugin. Disable it first(your system will be unstable), config cube settings and enable it then enable unity plugin. Now reset your unity "sudo unity --reset" or log out.

Answer (score 2):

Install compiz-plugins-extra
`sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra`

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/compiz-plugins-extra

Answer (score 0):

What you can also try is, downloading compizFusion from the ubuntu software centre, which will give you a few extra effects.